# Прокси для работы с https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/balance 3proxy

Tags: python, api, proxy

Написал скрипт на питоне для получения баланса карты, в приватбанке существует привязка мерчантов к IP. пробовал подключаться через бесплатные прокси, в принципе работает, но бесплатные прокси вещь очень не постоянная. Возникла мысль поднять свой собственный прокси сервер например 3proxy, чтобы прописать в мерчант приватбанка свой ip и порт и потом подсоединяться с любого устройства прописав в скрипте связь через этот мой прокси. Возможно ли такое в принципе? Буду благодарен за советы. Может есть какой то другой вариант?

Comment: Ну вообще такие вещи делаются через VPN, если конечно не хочешь что-бы тебе баланс раздербанили. А вообще в мире навалом очень дешевых VPN и HTTP хостингов.  Как пример https://secure.veesp.com/?affid=380 - там выделенные сервера по цене бутылки водки хоть VPN хоть прокси ставь. Я бы реализовывал в виде HTTP сервиса с обновлением баланса через cron раз в 30 минут.

Comment: Была и такая мысль, купил прокси на PROXY6.net

выдает ошибку
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.privatbank.ua', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /p24api/balance (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)')))

Comment: Не, я всё-же сторонник VPS на одну впс-ку можно и сам скрипт поставить, и не думаешь о том где он там крутится, сколько трафик кушает. А если что SSH всегда под рукой прям на телефоне подправить что надобно.